# Stored procedure parameters do not match in a different Oracle DB version

Tags: c#, oracle

To execute the queries against my Oracle database I'm using the old library `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary`.

I **can** execute the stored procedures against an Oracle database without errors with the following version:

- Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Prod
- PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
- CORE  10.2.0.5.0  Production
- TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production*

Using the same C# code, the same stored procedures, but against an Oracle database that has a different version, I get the error

> The number of parameters does not match number of values for stored procedure

The version is different but the database itself is the same. Same tables, same structure, etc.

The version of the other database is:

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
- PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- "CORE 11.2.0.4.0  Production"
- TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
- NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

The stored procedures are defined in a package in which there are header and body definitions.

Here I show my C# code that calls one of the stored procedures:

```
public string ComputeBlocks(string storeToExecute, string year, string month, DocumentTypeToSelect documentType)
{
        try
        {
            this.CreateDatabaseConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Error("Error during database connection.", ex);
            throw new ConnectingToDatabaseException("ConnectionError", ex);
        }

        try
        {
            object[] results = new object[4];

            DbCommand objCMD = this.DatabaseConnection.GetStoredProcCommand(storeToExecute, results);

            _logger.Info("Creato comando stored procedure " + storeToExecute);

            this.DatabaseConnection.SetParameterValue(objCMD, "YearDoc", year);
            this.DatabaseConnection.SetParameterValue(objCMD, "MonthDoc", month);
            this.DatabaseConnection.SetParameterValue(objCMD, "DocType", documentType);

            int storeExecutionResult = this.DatabaseConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(objCMD);

            return (string)this.DatabaseConnection.GetParameterValue(objCMD, "blocks");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this._logger.Error("Error during query execution.", ex);
            throw new ExecuteQueryException("Error", ex);
        }
}
```

The error occurs on this line of code:

```
DbCommand objCMD = this.DatabaseConnection.GetStoredProcCommand(storeToExecute, results);
```

Any advice?

**Update**: libraries used:

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
```

Comment: What driver do you use to connect to Oracle?

Comment: In my pc i'm using "Oracle Instant Client 10.2". In the remote machine that points to the Oracle DB that produces errors i've installed the latest version of "Oracle Client" (12).

Comment: And you are using ODP.NET?

Comment: No i'm not. I'm using the old Microsoft Enterprise library.

Comment: They will need a provider, too. The Microsoft classes were deprecated around the time the 10 to 11 change happened. Maybe you should get the Enterprise library to use ODP.NET.

Comment: I just can't. Why i can execute standard queries but i've issues with stored procedures parameters? Ops i'm sorry.. how can i achieve what you've said?